# Is there any way to show a custom message when a user opens Outlook in safe mode?

Tags: outlook, safe-mode

We've built some automated governance around sending emails from Outlook using VSTO. Users are able to avoid this automation if they open Outlook in safe mode.

Is there any way we can provide a custom message to the effect that "running outlook in safe mode is against company policy" if a user does this?

We've researched Stack Overflow, other online resources. Google mostly just shows "what is safe mode" or "how do I open in safe mode" which is not what we need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way of doing so. You may try using something like [detours.net](https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net).